# Can't add items to Many2many in Odoo 12 EE

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I defined a `Many2many` field for `ir.attachemnt`. The problem is i can' see the `Add an item` link to add the records.

***.py**

```py
attachment_ids = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', string='Attachments')
```

***.xml**

```xml
<notebook>
          <page string='Attachments'>
            <field name="attachment_ids"/>

          </page>
</notebook>
```

I also tried this:

```xml
<field name="attachment_ids" widget="many2many" />
```

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only two thing that make Odoo behave like this.

1. Your view is in edit mode but I think I'm seeing a place holder `comments` this means it's not the case
2. Your user is not allowed to create an `ir.attachment` which is more likely not the case
3. Your field is readonly.

If not one of this cases these is wired but if you didn't understand what happen you can force that link to appear by using embedded tree with create attribute set to true

```
     <field..... >
             <tree create='1'>
             ....
```

Comment: `<tree create='1'>` helped me. Thanks @EasyOdoo

Answer (score 0):

It'a a bug. If you have more many2many fields in the some class and for one of this you haven't right access rules, all the many2many fields are showed in readonly mode.

Comment: Is there a source for this?